# Travis-ci.com API get builds history for repo. after_number parameter has no effect

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-api

I want to extract some data for analyses from travis-ci.com api.
As first step i need list of all builds for specific repository for last 30 days.
Ive used travis-ci.com api.

```
curl https://api.travis-ci.com/repos/wixplosives/pleb/builds?after_number=293062563 -H "Authorization: token MYTOKENGOESHERE" -H "User-Agen: Core3Client/1.0.0" -H "Accept: application/vnd.travis-ci.2.1+json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -o travis-builds.json
```

But result is always same 50 latest builds. Looks like after_number parameter has not effect on result. Am i missing something?

Comment: Sorry for bad code but here it is quick and dirty, how to get list of all builds from travis for specific period of time

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import datetime
import json

travis_token = 'your_travis_token'

def saveListToFile(list, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as filehandle:
        json.dump(list, filehandle)


def getBuildList(slug: str,buildNumber: int):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'token '+travis_token,
        'User-Agent': 'Core3Client/1.0.0',
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.travis-ci.2.1+json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    urlparams = {}
    if buildNumber !=0:
        urlparams = {
            'after_number': buildNumber,
        }

    url = str.format('https://api.travis-ci.com/repos/{}/builds', slug)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers,params=urlparams)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('Error', response.status_code, response.text)
        return {}
    else:
        return response.json()

def getJob(jobid: int):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'token '+travis_token,
        'User-Agent': 'Core3Client/1.0.0',
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.travis-ci.2.1+json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    urlparams = {}

    url = str.format('https://api.travis-ci.com/jobs/{}', jobid)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers,params=urlparams)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('Error', response.status_code, response.text)
        return {}
    else:
        return response.json()

def getBuildMeta(builds):
    minBuildId = 0
    minDateStr = ''
    arraOfJobs = []
    for build in builds['builds']:
        if minBuildId == 0 or build['number'] < minBuildId:
            minBuildId = build['number']
            if build['started_at'] != None:
                minDateStr = build['started_at']
        arraOfJobs.extend(build['job_ids'])
    minDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(minDateStr,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    return minBuildId,minDate,arraOfJobs

def serializeAllJobsForTravis():
    date1 = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0)
    minBuildTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    minBuildNum = 0
    i = 0
    arrayOfJobsTotal = []
    while minBuildTime > date1:
        i = i + 1
        builds = getBuildList('wixplosives/component-studio', minBuildNum)
        minBuildNum, minBuildTime, arraOfJobs = getBuildMeta(builds)
        arrayOfJobsTotal.extend(arraOfJobs)
        print(i, minBuildNum, minBuildTime)
    saveListToFile(arrayOfJobsTotal, 'jobs.txt')
```